# What is the concept of "Centrifugal Force"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Pls explain the intuitive concept of [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) in different situations.

Answer (score 4):

An object can only move in a circle if a force continually pulls it towards the centre of the circle. This force is called the centripetal (“centre seeking”) force. An object moving in a circle is not in mechanical equilibrium, so there is no force that balances the centripetal force. *However* if we treat the object as if it were in mechanical equilibrium then we have to introduce a fictitious force to balance the centripetal force and this fictitious force is the centrifugal (“centre avoiding”) force.

If you are on a roundabout you have to hold to something or lean against something to provide the centripetal force. Your brain assumes that your body is in mechanical equilibrium because it is not moving relative to the objects around it (this is often correct) so it feels like there is some mysterious centrifugal force trying to throw you off the roundabout. In the same way, if you are in a lift accelerating upwards, you feel heavier because you brain interprets the additional force on your feet as being due to a greater weight pulling you down.

Comment: Using the term equilibrium is misleading here. The question is whether the frame of reference is accelerated or not. (A trolley rolling at a constant speed along a straight track is not in static equilibrium either, but in the cabin there are no pseudo-forces).

Comment: @SebastianRiese A trolley rolling at a constant speed along a straight track is in *mechanical equilibrium* - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium. I have edited my answer to be more specific about the type of equilibrium that I meant.

Comment: I have one very important question here. If i am in inertial frame looking static object on the ground. Force due to gravity pull the object toward center of the earth but the balancing force let say Normal Force act opposite and equal in magnitude. This normal force is caused by the surface. It is not a fictitious force. $\vec{F}_{g} = \vec{N}$ . If this the case in rotating frame the same case should happen centrifugal force should be arise from surface. This is not fictitious why we called this fictitious.Pls explain.

Comment: @123 If you want to understand more about fictitious forces such as centrifugal force, I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force, look at the related answers on this site, or post a separate question of your own.

Comment: @gandalf61 Ow, you are right, I have to admit, I never used that term outside of static considerations, but it seems to be common to define mechanic equilibrium outside of statics as being free of forces (I just checked and was surprised). So today I learned, and sorry for the spam.

Answer (score 2):

Centrifugal force is a pseudo force and it doesn't exist when motion is observed from an inertial frame of reference i.e. non accelerating frame.

For example take the case of  moon.   As seen from a man in outer space there is only one force on the moon acting towards the earth and this is along the center of the orbit in which moon is revolving and this centripetal force is responsible for its revolution . So if centrifugal force existed here,  the moon should have followed a **tangential path** since the centripetal force would be balanced by the centrifugal force but it doesn't happen.

But as seen from the rotating frame of reference i.e. the moon you would say the moon is at rest. And what caused the balance to your pull towards the earth is the **centrifugal force**. It doesn't exist from an *inertial frame* but does exist in a **non inertial frame of reference** . So you do feel a push outward when standing on a merry go round because you ( the observer) are on a rotating frame.

So it's just a matter of frame and nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first Centripetal force. Centripetal force is the force that is needed to keep an object moving in a circular/curved path and is directed inward toward the center of rotation. *Centrifugal* force is defined as the apparent force that is felt by that same object but directed outward from the centre of rotation. They both have the same magnitude given by

$$F = m \frac{v^2}{r}$$

For example if you tied a ball to a string and swung it in circular motion, the tension in the string $T$ would be generated by this force. Provided the string does not break, both forces are balanced by so that

$$T -  m \frac{v^2}{r} =0$$

Comment: Means in this case tension in the string is centrifugal force? but, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force says srting force is centripetal force.

Comment: No. I said the magnitude of the centrifugal force is equal to the magnitude of the Centripetal force. However the direction of the centripetal force is the same as the tension force and both have the same magnitude.